# Find most recent file in a directory (in Windows System) in R

Tags: r

I have few files in a directory(C:\MY_FOLDER\Freeze). Lets say i have two file with datetime infront of that. As shown below :

[image]

I have to read the most recent file in R. Help me please. I tried searching for the answers, but everywhere its in regarding with Linux system. "ctime" & "mtime" not working here.

Comment: You should include the code you have tried, even if it doesn't run on your Windows system.

Comment: See the output of `file.info(dir('C:/MY_FOLDER?Freeze'))` . There will be a column for modified time. Select the row with the highest time

Comment: Can you explain why "mtime" is not working in your use case? In the image you have posted the time is "Date modified", meaning, "mtime".

Comment: @Rohit Or maybe `file.mtime` is simpler, if the OP just wants that value.

Comment: I suggest `file.list(…, full.names = TRUE) %>% extract(which.max(file.mtime(.)))`

Answer (score 57):

We can use `file.info` with `list.files`. `list.files` would list all the files in the interested directory and `file.info` would give the details of all those files. We then get most recently modified file using `which.max` on `mtime` and then get the corresponding path of that file.

```
df <- file.info(list.files("/path/to/your/directory", full.names = T))
rownames(df)[which.max(df$mtime)]

#[1] "/path/to/your/directory/Interested_file.xlsx"
```

You can then use any of the commands to read csv or excel from that path.

Comment: This question is marked as duplicate, but I find this solution much more effective than the solutions on what was deemed the 'original' post.  Thank you!

Comment: How would you perform further subsetting of the dataframe, say to only use files with `isdir == FALSE`?  I have tried using `df <- subset(df, isdir == FALSE)` with no success.

Answer (score 5):

Another way of identifying the most recent file in the directory:

```
tmpshot <- fileSnapshot("/path/to/your/directory")
rownames(tmpshot$info[which.max(tmpshot$info$mtime),])
```

Comment: Is there a way of doing this but with directories? To know which one is the newest?

Comment: I have the same question as @Mel