# Get file details from a specific folder in windows

Tags: r, file, package

I am attempting to get a list of file details from specific folders, just as they are shown in any generic windows explorer folder.

My need is just to tabulate information such as name, size, date modified, date of creation, author, etc

```
name          extension       date modified size
store_tracker      .csv 2018-12-27 16:06:31 36kb
```

Is there any base [r](/questions/tagged/r) function that does it, or some other package?

`list.files` does not solve the problem since it only displays the file names

`file.info` has only a few output values and I needed to export some more information, which are displayed in any generic windows folder, such as the file "author" and "creation date".

Comment: `file.info(path_to_file_name)` gives information about files. This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870554/find-most-recent-file-in-a-directory-in-windows-system-in-r/

Comment: This is not a duplicate in the sense that `file.info` does not return a whole range of information a typical folder can show, e.g., "author" and "creation date"

Comment: `fs::file_info()` might be useful

Comment: Thanks. If you want to, post as an aswer so I can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested above, fs::file_info and some list manipulation does the trick.

```
library(fs)
files <- list.files(all.files = F, recursive = T, full.names = T)
details <- lapply(files, fs::file_info)
details.df <- data.frame(Reduce(rbind, details))
details.df$size <- as.numeric(details.df$size) # convert fs_bytes to number
```