# how to extract date in file name and sort it to find the latest file?

Tags: r, date, xlsx

I currently have several files in a folder. It contains everyday updates on stock. It's looked like this.

```
Onhand Harian 12 Juli 2019.xlsx
Onhand Harian 13 Juli 2019.xlsx
Onhand Harian 14 Juli 2019.xlsx... and so on.
```

I would like to read ONLY the latest excel file by using the date on the file name. How to done this? thanx in advance

Comment: are the month names in german?

Comment: Given that the latest excel file corresponds to the file with the latest creation date, you could also look at the creation time instead of the file name: `files <- file.info(dir("/path/to/folder")); files[which.max(files$ctime)]`

Comment: @JorisChau that's great. thanx so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of your files contain the same name, you can do

```
#List all the file names in the folder
file_names <- list.files("/path/to/folder/", full.names = TRUE)

#Remove all unwanted characters and keep only the date
#Convert the date string to actual Date object
#Sort them and take the latest file
file_to_read <- file_names[order(as.Date(sub("Onhand Harian ", "", 
       sub(".xlsx$", "", basename(file_names))), "%d %B %Y"), decreasing = TRUE)[1]]
```

Apparently, if your files are generated everyday you can also select them based on their creation or modification time using `file.info` ? Details in [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50870554/find-most-recent-file-in-a-directory-in-windows-system-in-r/) post.

Comment: This will return `c(NA, NA, NA)` because his locale is apparently German. Do you know how to make `as.Date` to understand German month names?

Comment: @January From `?strptime`, `%B - Full month name in the current locale.` So I think `%B` works based on user's locale already?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said: because his *file names* are apparently German. We don't know what his locale is. So, Nicodemus, if this solution does not work, try `Sys.setlocale(locale="de_DE.utf8")`.

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto You need not change the locale if it's already Indonesian.

Comment: @RonakShah i have apply your code,but the file that is called were the first created. How to change it so i could call the latest file created? thanx

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto which file name came in `file_to_read` ?  and which one do you expect ?

Comment: @RonakShah yes the 'file_to_read'. It didnt read the latest. it reads the first file

Comment: @RonakShah if i want to read the latest file, just change 'decreasing' into 'increasing'?

Comment: @RonakShah it shows error like this after i change it to increasing "Error in order(c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), increasing = TRUE,  : 
  argument lengths differ".

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto use `decreasing = FALSE` instead. There is no `increasing = TRUE`. Also I shared a link in my answer which might be helpful as well.

Comment: @RonakShah if i want to change the order basis (instead i use the date in the file name, i want to use date of file creation), so i change the code to this
"file_to_read <- file_names[order(files$ctime, decreasing = TRUE)[1]]". I have try it but it didnt work

Comment: @NicodemusSigitSutanto First do `df <- file.info(list.files("/path/to/your/directory", full.names = TRUE))` then use `rownames(df)[which.max(df$ctime)]` You should get most recent file.

Comment: THANX SO MUCH @RonakShah. You are really helpful :). I've been spending 4 hours to find out the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyverse)

x <- c("Onhand Harian 12 Juli 2019.xlsx",
       "Onhand Harian 13 Juli 2019.xlsx",
       "Onhand Harian 14 Juli 2019.xlsx")

lookup <- set_names(seq_len(12),
                    c("Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli",
                      "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"))

enframe(x, name = NULL, value = "txt") %>%
  mutate(txt_extract = str_extract(txt, "\\d{1,2} \\D{3,9} \\d{4}")) %>% # September is longest ..
  separate(txt_extract, c("d", "m", "y"), remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(m = sprintf("%02d", lookup[m]),
         d = sprintf("%02d", as.integer(d))) %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(str_c(y, m, d), format = "%Y%m%d")) %>%
  filter(date == max(date)) %>%
  pull(txt) 
#  "Onhand Harian 14 Juli 2019.xlsx"
```